# Django medias(pictures) suddenly not loading

Tags: django, django-media

I am developing a website with Django, I had a lot of pictures in my project, uploaded from the admin panel and saved in the Media folder which I created for these uploads separately, It was working fine and exact way I wanted in months, Suddenly they are just not loading, getting 404 for all of them,  without any change in project, they are just not loading.
My media path in Settings.py :

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

I have added this to the end of my urls.py of the app:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and as i said, it was working fine for a long, suddenly this happened

edit: I just figured it out that this is happening when I am using redirect function in one of my views

Comment: did you try to upload new picture is it loading?

Comment: yes, I re-uploaded them, I uploaded new images, literally everything, nothing happened, still not loading

Comment: Did you update the `debug` value on `settings.py`? When this value is false django does not serve the media and you should give it to web servers like nginx

Comment: yes, I tried the Debug=False & True, both same situation, I even didn't change the value before this bug, It was fine when debg=True, suddenly in the True this happened

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue and this helps me :

Add this in your urls.py in the urlpatterns list :

```
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
# YOUR URLS ARE HERE
]
```

Of course stay in Debug=True in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     # other URLs ... 
]

# If DEBUG=True in the settings file
if settings.DEBUG:
     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

So we're adding `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to the `urlpatterns` if `DEBUG=True` in the `settings.py` file. This gives a better management in some sense.